# Dynamically decide which GPU to run on - TF on NVIDIA docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, cuda, nvidia-docker

I have a queue of models, which I allow only 2 to be executed in parallel, since I have 2 GPUs.
For that, in the beginning of my code I try to determine which GPU is available by using [`GPUtil`](https://github.com/anderskm/gputil). Maybe its relevant, this code in run inside a docker container that was launched using the `--runtime=nvidia` flag.

The code that determines which GPU to run on, looks like this:

```
import os
import GPUtil
gpu1, gpu2 = GPUtil.getGPUs()

available_gpu = gpu1 if gpu1.memoryFree > gpu2.memoryFree else gpu2
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = str(available_gpu.id)

import tensorflow as tf
```

Now, I launched two scripts this way (with a slight delay until the first one occupied a GPU) but both of them tried to use the same GPU!

I went further to examine the problem - I manually set the `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'` and let the model run.
As it was training, I checked the output of `nvidia-smi` and saw the following

```
user@server:~$ docker exec awesome_gpu_container nvidia-smi
Mon Mar 12 06:59:27 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.111                Driver Version: 384.111                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   50C    P2   131W / 280W |   5846MiB /  6075MiB |     81%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P8    14W / 200W |      2MiB /  8114MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

And I notice that while I've set the visible device to be `1` it is actually running on 0

I stress again, that my mission is while queuing multiple models that each one that start running will decide for itself which GPU to use.

I explored `allow_soft_placement=True`, but that allocated the memory on both GPUs so I stopped the process.

Bottom line, how can I make sure my training scripts only use one GPU, and make them choose the free one?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in your code. os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DIVICES']

Comment: it is a error in the writing of the post, not in the code obviously

Comment: Not obviously. I and others can only go by what you post. If the code in your question isn't actually what you use, how could anyone diagnose the problem?

Comment: We could argue that - because in the nvidia-smi output you can see only one is working - but that's irrelevant now, i fixed it

Comment: Having not set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to anything would be completely consistent with your problem, but whatever. What happens if you run just the TF script from a shell with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` set to the second device. Does it do as you want?

Comment: When I don't set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to anything, tf automatically allocates memory on both devices, even though it uses only one. When I run a script from the shell, setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE to 1, and uses the actual 0, and when vice versa. Problem is when I try to figure out dynamically using GPUtil, it gets the id of the correctly available GPU, but assigning it actually assigns the second one (since the IDs are reversed strangely)

Comment: So your question is really about differences in enumeration ID order from different libraries?

Comment: Not actually, I could use any other solution that given queued script each one would choose the available GPU

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars), the default device enumeration used by CUDA is "fastest first":

> CUDA_​DEVICE_​ORDER
>
> FASTEST_FIRST, PCI_BUS_ID, (default is FASTEST_FIRST)
>
> FASTEST_FIRST causes CUDA to guess which device is
> fastest using a simple heuristic, and make that device 0, leaving the
> order of the rest of the devices unspecified.
>
> PCI_BUS_ID orders devices by PCI bus ID in ascending order.

If you set `CUDA_​DEVICE_​ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID` the CUDA ordering will match the device ordering shown by `nvidia-smi`.

Since you are using docker, you can also enforce a stronger isolation with our runtime:
`docker run --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 ...`
But that's at container startup time.

Comment: So what should I do so that the script would define the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to be only the most available GPU ?

Comment: CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 

CUDA_​DEVICE_​ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID